# save all textfields by clicking on one update button

Tags: php, database, javascript

we have multi vendor site. we are giving option for vendor to edit all textfields of multiple products and save all by clicking on one "**Update**" button....

we are using following code for saving price of one text field.

**Price**

```
public function updateFieldPriceAction(){
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);      
    $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
    $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));
    //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEditProductId($id);

    try{
    $upd_price = $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);        
    //$product->setData('price', $upd_price);
    $product->setPrice($upd_price);

    //$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($id);
    //$stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
    //$stockItem->setData('qty', $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty'));
    $product->save();

    echo $price = $product->getPrice();
    echo $name = $product->getName();

    $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 
    //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated'));


    //endif;
    }catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Not Saving"; exit;    
    Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    }

  }
```

we are using following code to save quantity of one text field.

**Quantity**

```
public function updateFieldAction(){
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));
        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEditProductId($id);
        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($id);
        $stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
        $stockItem->setData('qty', $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty'));

        $stockItem->save();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 
        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated'));
      }
```

we are using following code to save all textfields of price and quantity by **single update button**. Price is working. but quantity is not working.

**controller.php**

```
public function massupdatesellerproAction(){
    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        if(!$this->_validateFormKey()){
             $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');
        }
        $ids= $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_mass_update');
        $price= $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');
        $qty = $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty');
        foreach ($ids as $key => $value) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($value);
    $product->setPrice($price[$key]);
    $product->setQty($qty[$key]);
    $product->save();
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess( Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Products has been sucessfully saved from your account'));
        $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');


    }}
```

[image]

Comment: post you fields too..

Comment: tell me what code fields code you want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve functionality with below code

```
function updateAllField(product_id) 
{ 
var priceId = '#price_'+ product_id; // for price 
var SpecpriceId = '#specialprice_'+ product_id; // for special price 
var quantity = '#quantity_'+ product_id; // for quantity 
var currprice='#curr_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedprice_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/singlerowupdate/')?>'; 
$price = $wk_jq(priceId).val(); 
$specialprice = $wk_jq(SpecpriceId).val(); 
$quantity = $wk_jq(quantity).val(); 
$wk_jq(currprice).val($price); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 
parameters: {id: product_id, price: $price, speprice: $specialprice,quantity:$quantity}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}
```

for controller

```
public function singlerowupdateAction(){
    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        if(!$this->_validateFormKey()){
             $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');
        }
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $price= $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');
        $speprice= $this->getRequest()->getParam('speprice');
        $qty = $this->getRequest()->getParam('quantity');

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
    $product->setPrice($price);
    $product->setSpecialPrice($price);
    $product->setQty($qty);
    $product->save();

        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess( Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Products has been sucessfully saved from your account'));
        $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');


    }}
```

Comment: i added your code, but its not working....

Comment: it is a sample code add you original ids. and on button click call this function